# Error with getStaticPaths() and getStaticProps() with nested routes in NextJS 14

Tags: reactjs, next.js, nested-routes, nextjs-dynamic-routing

I am making a blog with two level nested routes: example.com/blogs/[chapterID]/[postID] The static posts saved in local folder (outside the app folder) as markdown files.

[image]

The urls are stored in the blogs.json.

```
[
  {
    "header": "Header for Category1",
    "id": "category1",
    "topicList": [
      {
        "title": "post1 title",
        "url": "cat1-post1.md"
      },
      {
        "title": "post2 title",
        "url": "cat1-post2.md"
      },
      {
        "title": "post3 title",
        "url": "cat1-post3.md"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "header": "Header for Category 2",
    "id": "category2",
    "topicList": [
      {
        "title": "Cat2 Post1 title",
        "url": "cat2-post1.md"
      },
      {
        "title": "Cat2 Post2 title ",
        "url": "cat2-post2.md"
      },
      {
        "title": "Cat2 Post3 title ",
        "url": "cat2-post3.md"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "header": "Header for Category 3",
    "id": "category3",
    "topicList": [
      {
        "title": "Cat3 Post1 title",
        "url": "cat3-post1.md"
      },
      {
        "title": "Cat3 Post2 title ",
        "url": "cat3-post1.md"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

The page works but I am having hardtime to generate static paths and props.

My page.tsx inside [postID] is-

```
    import React from 'react'
    
    import fs from "fs"
    
    import Markdown from "react-markdown"
    import rehypeKatex from "rehype-katex"
    import remarkMath from "remark-math"
    import rehypeRaw from "rehype-raw"
    import matter from "gray-matter"
    import 'katex/dist/katex.min.css'
    
    import BlogMenu from '../../blogs.json'
    import path from "path"
    
    
    
    const allPosts = BlogMenu.flatMap(({ header, id, topicList }) =>
      topicList.map((topics) => ({
    
        sectionName: header,
        sectionId: id,
        ...topics,
    
      })),
    );
    
    
    const folder = path.join(process.cwd(), 'src/BlogPages');// declare it outside of app folder
    
    const getPostContent = (chapterID:string, postID: string) => {
      
      const file = `${folder}/${chapterID}/${postID}.md`;
      const content = fs.readFileSync(file, "utf8");
      const matterResult = matter(content);
      return matterResult;
    };
    
    
    
    
    export async function getStaticPaths() {
    
      return {
        paths: allPosts.map((post) => ({
          params: {
            chapterID: post.sectionId,
            postID: post.url
          },
        })),
        fallback: false,
      };
    }
    export async function getStaticProps(chapterID:string, postID: string) {
      
      const postProps = getPostContent(chapterID, postID) // Retrieve data for given type/slug pair
    
      return {
        props: {
          data: postProps
        }
      }
    }
    
    
    
    const BlogPage = (props: any) => {
      const chapterID = props.params.chapterID
      const postID = props.params.postID;
      
      const post = getPostContent(chapterID, postID)
    
      return (
    
        <>
    
          <h1>{post.data.title}</h1>
          <hr className="my-6 border border-dashed bg-teal-600 h-0.5" />
          <article className="prose lg:prose-xl">
            <Markdown remarkPlugins={[remarkMath]} rehypePlugins={[rehypeKatex, rehypeRaw]}>
              {post.content}</Markdown>
          </article>
        </>
    
      )
    }
    
    export default BlogPage
```

When I run `npm run build` it shows the error-

```
> next build

   ▲ Next.js 14.0.4

 ✓ Creating an optimized production build    
 ✓ Compiled successfully
   Linting and checking validity of types  ...Failed to compile.

src/app/(routes)/blogs/[chapterID]/[postID]/page.tsx
Type error: Page "src/app/(routes)/blogs/[chapterID]/[postID]/page.tsx" does not match the required types of a Next.js Page.
  "getStaticPaths" is not a valid Page export field.
```

And for getStaticProps() I am getting the error-

```
File path:
  ./src/app/(routes)/blogs/[chapterID]/[postID]/page.tsx
 ⨯ ./src/app/(routes)/blogs/[chapterID]/[postID]/page.tsx
ReactServerComponentsError:

"getStaticProps" is not supported in app/. Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching
```

Any suggestion about solving the error will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lots of searching, it seems that since NextJS 13 they have introduced new `app` directory and calling `getStaticProps()` or `getStaticPaths()` inside the `app` will cause the error. This error can be solved by using `generateStaticParams()` instead.

```
export async function generateStaticParams() {
  return allPosts.map((post) => ({
    chapterID: post.sectionId,
    postID: post.url

  }))
}
```

I have removed my `getStaticProps()` and `getStaticPaths()` functions and used the above code to generate static slug. Hope it will help someone. You will find more details about `generateStaticParams()` in [this link](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/generate-static-params).